# Addition in MySQL using information from columns to create a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, integer, addition

I have three MySQL columns, Name, Goals, Assists (G and A respectively). I want to calculate points by adding Goals and Assists together, and then sort Names by points.

What I tried was;

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM stats WHERE Points=G+A ORDER BY Points";
```

This didn't work, does anyone have any suggestions on basic addition in MySQL using integers from separate columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
$SQL = "SELECT Name, Goals, Assists, (Goals+Assists) AS SumColumn FROM STATUS ORDER BY Points";
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name, (G+A) AS points FROM stats ORDER BY points

Comment: Getting syntax errors, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT name, (G+A) AS points ORDER BY points' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL="SELECT *, (Goals+Assists) AS totalPoints FROM stats ORDER BY totalPoints";
```